# Upshot without DbDataController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, upshot

I was going through the single page applications of the MVC4 and I could see that upshot.js interacting with the WebApi which is really cool. But going through the controller code i found that the Controller derives from the DbDataController which directly consumes my EntityFramework DbContext to do database operations. But what if I want to do those operations, say like my models are not entities , but plain models which I need to store into a NoSql database like RavenDb. What should I do so that I could  get all those features of Upshot, but the database operations I should be able to do it ? And how i will give those metadata of the models to the upshot?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and after a lot of research; I comes with a conclusion: Microsoft Single Page App is not mature and this MVC Template removed from VS 2012.

See this Videos for JayData ... that thing makes me drool
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlJHgj1y0CU

And for client navigation between pages in your app use Sammy JS.
It seems that John Papa recommends this library in his next videos in Pluralight.com
http://johnpapa.net/spapost2